# Run a batch file using "Batch" command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am currently working on a project in which the deliverable is a `.sh` file. When I run the file using `./file.sh` it works just fine. But according to the prof. we have to run the file using this statement. `Batch file.sh`. This does not work, and the errors returned are `batch accepts no parameters`. Which makes sense after reading the man page.

What is the proper way to use the batch command? Is it even possible to run it the way that the professor wants?

Comment: Your prof meant `bash`, not `batch`, big difference. He would have stated bash as there are multple shells on *nix and he specifically wants you to use bash. You can obviously use a shebang instead in the script i.e `#!/usr/bin/bash` which will tell the system which shell to use and you can simply run `./file.sh` given the fact that is also has execution rights.

Comment: @jctamin FYI Unix doesn't use file prefixes to determine the type of a file contents, and Unix commands shouldn't end in a prefix (otherwise if you in future rewrite your shell script as C or perl or something you'd have to rename it and change everywhere that calls it) so saying `the deliverable is a .sh file.` isn't great phrasing since "a .sh file" could contain anything at all and a command that contains a shell script shouldn't have any suffix, .sh or otherwise. What I think you're trying to say is simply `the deliverable is a shell script`.

Comment: Ah I see, that is helpful to know. I am still learning and appreciate the explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, the file you are trying to execute shouldn't be executed with **Batch** but **Bash/Shell**.

Following [Batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Filename_extensions), Batch is not supposed to run programs with the *sh* extension (*sh* stands for *shell*).

You can validate what interpreter the program you are trying to use should be run with with the following ways:

1. Checking the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))
2. Using the [file command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) (i.e. *file ./your_program.sh*)

After finding the correct interpreter, you can run the program with calling it (i.e. *sh ./your_program.sh*)